# compare key and values at corresponding index in python

Tags: python, dictionary, match, key-value

There is dictionary in python.key and value spelling is compared.if the mistake is greater than or equal to 2 than print incorrect

input={"their":"thuyr"}

output=incorrect(because t=t,h=h but e!=u,i!=y).

My problem is that i was unable to compare t==t,h==h,e==u,i==y.
The below code shows count value 22 but count value must be 2 because only two words mismatches with their

```
def find_correct(words_dict):
    count=0
    for key,value in words_dict.items():
        for val in value:
            for ky in key:
                if(val!=ky):
                    count+=1  
    return count     

print(find_correct({"their":"thuor"}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're using nested loops. It's comparing each letter of "t" in "their" with each 5 letters in "thuor". Instead, just use a single loop like this:

```
def find_correct(words_dict):
count=0
for key,value in words_dict.items():
    for val, ky in zip(value, key):
        if(val!=ky):
            count+=1  
return count
```